# sql getting error with '->>' operator

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `getAssetDetailsforPDF`(
) BEGIN
Select
    class.Name as AssetName,
    getOperatingZoneName(
        ifnull(getoperatingzone(class.ID), 0)
    ) as OperatingZone,
    getTimetoFailure(
        class.ID
    ) as TagValue,
    class1.Name as LineName,
    details.Defintion - > > '$."Asset ID"' as definition
from
    asset_classification class
    left join
        asset_classification class1
    on  class1.ParentId = 2
    left join
        asset_details details
    on  details.Id in(
            select
                class.ID
        )
Where
    class.MCT_typeId = 5
and class.ParentId in(
        Select
            class1.ID
    )
group by
    class.Id
;
END
;
;
```

I have this sql query and I am getting error during import of sql file to the phpmyadmin database.

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."Asset ID"'*

**EDIT** 
Here is the version of MySql :

[image]

Comment: Check the join condition. details.Id in (select class.ID ) similarly in where clause as well.

Comment: this query works fine on other computer but not in mine. I think there is some issue in phpmyadmin

Comment: Whats the version of MySQL? `->>` was introduced in 5.7 according to the docs ([5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html) vs [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html)).

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be your MySQL does not support the operators like "->>'$...". Instead of that you can use MySQL's json_extract() function like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `getAssetDetailsforPDF`(
) BEGIN
Select
    class.Name as AssetName,
    getOperatingZoneName(
        ifnull(getoperatingzone(class.ID), 0)
    ) as OperatingZone,
    getTimetoFailure(
        class.ID
    ) as TagValue,
    class1.Name as LineName,
json_extract(details.Defintion,'$."Asset ID"') as definition

from
    asset_classification class
    left join
        asset_classification class1
    on  class1.ParentId = 2
    left join
        asset_details details
    on  details.Id in(
            select
                class.ID
        )
Where
    class.MCT_typeId = 5
and class.ParentId in(
        Select
            class1.ID
    )
group by
    class.Id
;
END
;
;
```